# What is reverse of @deprecated in java

Tags: java, annotations, deprecated

So, People use [`@Deprecated`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html) annotation for APIs that have been deprecated.

Is there any annotation that notifies users if the method is evolving and is not stable?

Comment: Not built-in but you can make your own. Like `@Beta`.

Comment: There's a [`@Beta` annotation in guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/annotations/Beta.html) that you could use.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32555597/annotating-unstable-classes-methods-for-javadoc

Comment: "Is there any annotation that notifies users if the method is evolving?"  @Darwin

Answer (score 4):

Afaik, it doesn't exist yet, you have to create your own.

[JEP277](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/277) define a `@Deprecated(EXPERIMENTAL)`, but it's just a proposition.

Answer (score 2):

In hadoop there is `InterfaceStability` annotation for these purposes. The funny thing is this annotation is not stable. I doubt such thing can appear in JDK.

```
@InterfaceAudience.Public
@InterfaceStability.Evolving
public class InterfaceStability {
  /**
   * Can evolve while retaining compatibility for minor release boundaries.; 
   * can break compatibility only at major release (ie. at m.0).
   */
  @Documented
  public @interface Stable {};

  /**
   * Evolving, but can break compatibility at minor release (i.e. m.x)
   */
  @Documented
  public @interface Evolving {};

  /**
   * No guarantee is provided as to reliability or stability across any
   * level of release granularity.
   */
  @Documented
  public @interface Unstable {};
}
```